# Need help on DB2 "call @some.thing(?,?)" syntax

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I just started a new job.
There are a lot of interesting things that I need to know simultaneously.
Right now it will be very helpful for me to know how can I get some info from some DB2 object which is called from the program by

```
call @some.thing(?,?)
```

I tried:

```
select text from some.routines where routinename = 'thing' 
select PROCNAME,TEXT from SYSIBM.SYSPROCEDURES 
select text from syscat.routines where routinename = 'thing'
```

but every time I get something like:

```
some.ROUTINES IS AN UNDEFINED NAME. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704,
DRIVER=4.8.86 
SYSCAT.ROUTINES IS AN UNDEFINED NAME. SQLCODE=-204,
SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.8.86 
SYSIBM.SYSPROCEDURES IS AN UNDEFINED
NAME. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.8.86
```

Althought `call @some.thing(?,?)` executed successfully in WID's Database Development View, I can't find an appropriate object while creating `JDBC outbound import`.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you running DB2 on?

If you're on Linux/Unix/Windows (LUW), then you should use [`SYSCAT.SYSROUTINES`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001045.html) (although you already mention that this one doesn't work, so I'm guessing that's not it).

For Mainframe DB2, you're looking for [`SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysroutinestable.htm).

If you're on iSeries, you probably want [`SYSROUTINES`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzmstcatalogtbls.htm) (though I'm not that familiar with the iSeries).

Comment: thanx @bhamby, but: select text   
from sysibm.sysroutines 
where schema='@SOME' and name='THING'   
and origin='N' and routinetype='P' and parm_count=2    

----->>>   *user* DOES NOT HAVE THE PRIVILEGE TO PERFORM OPERATION SELECT ON OBJECT SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.8.86